# Having more efficient code to return errors

Tags: php, performance, error-handling, coding-style, server-side

I have created a main class where all my main member activation deactivation functions are and all the other things related to them are also done

this main class(along with some main functions) is called from various places including through curl

Now lets take my activaton function(One of the main functions) in the class

```
activationFunction($data)
{
//use data to generate total, discount etc

$this->giveAffiliates($total);
if($this->_error){ return $this->_error;}

$this->activateOrder($total,$discount,id);
if($this->_error){ return $this->_error;}

$this->activatePlan($total,$discount,id);
if($this->_error){ return $this->_error;}

//similarily calling various functions which themselves call other functions

}

activatePlan()
{

try{

//call other functions and do necessary stuff for plan A

 }
catch(Exception $e)
{

$this->_error.="Error occurred while activating plan A";

}
//for plan B
try{

//call other functions and do necessary stuff for plan B

}
catch(Exception $e)
{

$this->_error.="Error occurred while activating plan B";

}

//for other plans similarily

 }
 }
```

Now the issue is having `if($this->_error){ return $this->_error;}` after each sub function call.(Total I am having around 35 such similar lines) 
I  require this as I need to send the error to the user and stop my code from running further.
But it is making my code long and not efficient. 
How can I reduce all these returns but show the user an error when one of the sub functions fails and try to keep my code structure as is.
I have to call the various subfunctions from each main function(This I cannot change, there will be only one class and various functions in it) and the errors will mostly have to be caught at each level and returned(very few simple errors are not returned and the code is allowed to continue running) . 
I have to also keep in mind that there can be various other functions be added to it later and it should be flexible enough to handle all that later

Comment: I don't think code execution efficiency is really the issue here. Rather code maintainability/readability.

Comment: Yes  code maintainability/readability is surely an issue if not the main issue

Answer (score 2):

You say "it is making my code long and not efficient."  What exactly do you mean "not efficient"?  Are you saying your code is slow?

If your code is too slow, then you need to profile your code with a tool like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) to find out exactly where your code is slow.  If you don't measure, you're just guessing as to what the problem is.

Comment: Well having to check if an error exists after each function seems wrong from my side and I wanted to know if there was a better way then checking 35 times if an error is present then send the error to the user.(I am sure such a code would not be called efficient and would surely make it slow as things get more complex and things are added to it later)

Comment: "seems wrong from my side" why?  Do you think it takes a lot of time?  I bet it doesn't.  You need to measure to know.  You are making a lot of guesses ("surely make it slow", "seems wrong", "I am sure such a code would not be called efficient"), but you need to use a tool to tell you if your guesses are right.  Otherwise, you're wasting your time speeding things up that are not actually slow.

Comment: Okay will test it with a tool also

Answer (score 0):

I would think each function should handle its own errors/exceptions. So that you don't push all the error handling into every pale that the function is called.  The caller for the function should not need to contain logic about how generating errors notifications from the function being called.

So say you have each function throw an exception on error condition. You could then do something like this:

```
activationFunction($data)
{
  //use data to generate total, discount etc
  try {
    $this->giveAffiliates($total);
    $this->activateOrder($total,$discount,id);
    $this->activatePlan($total,$discount,id);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    // throw the exception up the call chain
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

Comment: But lets say  in activatePlan function: My plan A updation has given no errors but my plan B has given errors, how will I identify that Plan B has given the updation error and not Plan A it may not be simple to identify what has given an error especially if the same table is getting updated with very few differences

Comment: @user1913849 That is all in what message you want to put into the Exception. You can be as specific as you want within the called function that is throwing the Exception as to what caused the Exception. You can also create you own custom Exception types that inherit from base Exception (this is actually good practice).  So say you had a DB connection problem, you could throw a DBException), or if you had a problem reading/writing to the filesystem you could throw an IOException. You can then handle caught exceptions differently based on their class if you like.

Comment: I cannot use "throw $e;" as it giving various errors when I am calling this class from various places and through curl which is doing all stuff and returning data in json format.I have to store it in a variable and then return that variable.Also as per the specific message that is returned a specific code is run from the caller file after the message is returned

Comment: @user1913849 OK then you can just store the string message from the exception in a variable.